# Is #define var bad with strcmp?

Tags: c, macros, strcmp

Can i compare`#define`varible and`char *` in strcmp as below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define var "hello"
int main()
{
char *p ="hello";
if(strcmp(p,var)==0)
printf("same\n");
else
printf("not same\n");
return 0;
}
```

Is there any risk comapre `#define` with `char *`as above example?

Comment: well, this example won't compile, so I guess there's that risk

Comment: nope, the preprocessor just replaces your token by the literal (that is, if the token matches the literal, which isn't the case in your code)

Comment: @UnholySheep I edit now this is will compile

Comment: The `var` name is *very* confusing. It is *not* a variable. By convention macro names are often all uppercase, e.g. `#define FOO "hello"`

Comment: Read wikipage on [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor); then read [documentation of `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) and reference on [preprocessor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor). You look confused!

Comment: Why in the world would one want to do this? Why not use a `const char[]`?

Comment: @Olaf can you please let me know advantage on using const char[] on #define please

Comment: @RohiniSingh: It should become obvious once you learned the language properly. A good C book might help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't trust us, trust the *preprocessor output*

File "foo.c"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define var "hello"

int main(void)
{
    char *buf="hello";

    if(strcmp(buf,var)==0) // Is this good
        printf("same");

    return 0;    
}
```

now:

```
gcc -E foo.c
```

lots of output because of standard system libraries then...:

```
# 5 "foo.c"
int main(void)
{
    char *buf="hello";

    if(strcmp(buf,"hello")==0)
        printf("same");

    return 0;
}
```

as you see your define has been safely replaced by the string literal.

When you have a doubt, just apply this method to make sure (more useful when converting to strings or concatenating tokens, there are traps to avoid)

In your case, you could also avoid the macro and use:

```
static const char *var = "hello";
```

which guarantees that only 1 occurrence of `"hello"` is set (saves data memory).

Comment: In review I am asked to remove #define with static cost not sure why

Comment: some people don't like macros. In that case, `static const char *` is also OK, and maybe is even better since it guarantees that the memory of the string isn't duplicated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Never use a macro if typesafe code will do as well (e.g. you will always get the same string, possibly save memory, etc.).

Comment: yeah, in that case, you can avoid it without any copy/paste issue. Macros are great to avoid copying/pasting code constructs or token concatenation (to some extent) but here's it's overkill (I added such conclusion in my answer if you noticed)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no risk to comapre #define with char* at all.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define var "hello"

    int main(void)
    {
        char *buf="hello";

        if(strcmp(buf,var)==0) // Is this good
            printf("same");

        return 0;    
    }
```